# How to compare two unordered columns by value with openpyxl and print the results for each row?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel file with two columns. The values in the columns are unordered. I know for sure that some of the cells from the source column exist in the target column, which is longer (240 rows compared to 191). How can I check if a value from the source column exists in the target column and then print to a column to the right from target column row by row i.e. "check" if the value from source exists and "missing" if it doesn't?

I assume it should follow this logic, but the value comparison itself seems tricky to me:

```
    for (source_row, target_row) in zip(ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=3, max_row=240),
                                        ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=7, max_row=240)):
        for (source_cell, target_cell) in zip(source_row, target_row):
            if target_cell in source_row: # doesn't seem to work
                ws.cell(column=10, row=target_cell.row).value = "check"
                break
            else:
                ws.cell(column=10, row=target_cell.row).value = "missing"
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of thing you should avoid using nested loops. Not only will they not work necessarily work in this case because you are only checking cell with cell and not cell against a set of values, nested loops can, ahem, quickly become slow, but also make debugging and flow control more difficult.

If you just want to know which values are in each column.

```
source = set((r[0] for r in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=240, min_col=3, max_col=3, values_only=True))
target = set((r[0] for r in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=240, min_col=7, max_col=7, values_only=True))

missing_value = target - source

You can now loop over the source cells and do the comparison:

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=240, min_col=3, max_col=3):
    for c in row:
        value = c.value in target and "check" or "missing"
        c.offset(rows=7).value = value
```